# Is it possible to persistently change the values of a VBO on the iPhone OpenGL ES 2.0 inside a vertex shader?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

I am an Opengl ES 2.0 newbie (and GLSL newbie) so forgive me if this is an obvious question.

If I have a VBO that I initialize once on the CPU at the start of my program is it possible  to then use vertex shaders to update it each frame without doing calculations on the cpu and then reuploading it to the GPU? Im not referring to sending a uniform and manipulating the data based on that. Instead I mean causing a persistent change in the VBO on the GPU itself.

So the simplest example I can think of would be adding 1 to the x,y and z component of gl_Position in the vertex shader every time the frame is rendered. This would mean that if I had only one vertex  and its initial position was set on the cpu to be (0,0,0,1) then after 30 frames it would (30,30,30,1) .

If this is possible what would it look like in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On modern desktop hardware (GL3/DX10) you can use transform feedback to write back the output of the vertex or geometry shader into a buffer, but I really doubt that the transform_feedback extension is supported on the iPhone (or in ES in general).

If PBOs are supported (what I also doubt), you can at least do it with some GPU-GPU copies. Just copy the vertex buffer into a texture (by binding it as a PBO), then render a textured fullscreen quad and perform the update in the fragment shader. After that you copy the framebuffer (which now contains the updated vertex data) into the vertex buffer (again by binding it as PBO). But this way you have to do 2 copies (although they should both happen completely on the GPU) and if the vertex data is floating point you will need to floating point render targets and framebuffer objects to be supported, too.

I think in ES the best solution would really be to do the computation on the CPU. Just hold a CPU copy (so you at least have no unneccessary GPU-CPU readback) and update the buffer data every frame (using `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` or even `GL_STREAM_DRAW` as buffer usage).

Maybe you can also completely prevent the persistent update by making the changes dependent on another simpler data. In your example you could just use a uniform for the frame number and set this as coordinate in the vertex shader every frame, but I don't know how complex your update function really is.

Comment: Im trying to do this: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter44.html and I cant do render-to-floating-point-texture on the iPhone because it isnt supported yet. So my next thought was to try and do some kind of update via a VBO but that also doesnt seem supported. Any idea how this might be done?

Comment: I do have float textures but I cant render into them.